Error con la librería FFT para una analizador de audio
Estoy intentando compilar un código que encontré para un analizador de audio matriz 8x8x4 con el Arduino, las matrices de led irán mostrando el audio, agregue la librería para FFT pero me arroja errores en el código.
Al inicio me lanzaba que no estaba agregada la librería pero como mencione, ya la agregue, al parecer la información que encontré sobre el código, si debería compilar, el error que me aparece es
exit status 1
Compilation error: 'arduinoFFT' does not name a type; did you mean 'ArduinoFFT'?
Busque mas ejemplos de FFT pero todos lo definen de esa forma
#include <arduinoFFT.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>

// Number of samples for FFT. Should be a power of 2.
const uint16_t samples = 64;  
uint16_t k = 0;
double vReal[samples];
double vImag[samples];
double ganancia = 0.5;

#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::PAROLA_HW
#define MAX_DEVICES  4

// Define pins for SPI
#define CLK_PIN   13  // or SCK
#define DATA_PIN  11  // or MOSI
#define CS_PIN    10  // or SS

arduinoFFT FFT = ArduinoFFT();

// SPI hardware interface
MD_MAX72XX mx = MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);

// We always wait a bit between updates of the display
#define DELAYTIME  100  // in milliseconds

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    mx.begin();
    mx.clear();
}

void loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
       vReal[i] = analogRead(A0) * ganancia;
       vImag[i] = 0;
       Serial.println(vReal[i]);
    }

    // Perform FFT
    FFT.Windowing(vReal, samples, FFT_WIN_TYP_RECTANGLE, FFT_FORWARD);
    FFT.Compute(vReal, vImag, samples, FFT_FORWARD);
    FFT.ComplexToMagnitude(vReal, vImag, samples);

    // Display the FFT results
    LedColumn(1, 0);
    LedColumn(9, 1);
    LedColumn(17, 2);
    LedColumn(25, 3);

    delay(DELAYTIME);
}

// Function to display the FFT results on the LED matrix
void LedColumn(int Fi, int Ci) {
    for (int i = Fi; i < Fi + 8; i++) {
        if (vReal[i] > 100) {
            mx.setColumn(Ci, B11111111);
        } else if (vReal[i] > 90) {
            mx.setColumn(Ci, B01111111);
        } else if (vReal[i] > 80) {
            mx.setColumn(Ci, B11111100);
        } else if (vReal[i] > 60) {
            mx.setColumn(Ci, B11111000);
        } else if (vReal[i] > 50) {
            mx.setColumn(Ci, B11110000);
        } else if (vReal[i] > 40) {
            mx.setColumn(Ci, B11100000);
        } else if (vReal[i] > 30) {
            mx.setColumn(Ci, B11000000);
        } else if (vReal[i] > 15) {
            mx.setColumn(Ci, B10000000);
        } else {
            mx.setColumn(Ci, B00000000);
        }
        Ci++;
    }
}


